# For the context of the storytelling aspect to deliver a message, what punctuation would be best used for the flow and structure of the speech given?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, writing, speech, story

Below is the body of work for the self-driven character that is declaring and establishing their agency. My question is if there should be a semicolon, comma, or period in-between "I'll keep walking. I'll keep moving forward." given the context and flow of the declaration speech:

> I do realize that this road will take time to travel. With the path that I have chosen, there is no way out of it, no turning back, and no telling what kind of adversity I'll face up ahead. My road will not always take me where I wish to go, and I am uncertain if I will live to see it to fruition, but I will travel down it nonetheless. No matter how much pain my own path brings, I'll keep walking. I'll keep moving forward. I will forge ahead with the guts to never give up and be the magnanimous individual I know I can be; but what's more important than how I achieve this goal, is the power to believe that it will happen. And the fact is, I believe in myself completely!

Comment: Why is this tagged "grammar"? It's still going to be the same words in the same order no matter.what,puncutation+you%use.

Comment: Punctuation seems all right, but the text is a bit repetitious.

Comment: Only prescriptivists would say that any is incorrect. I like the dramatic staccato effect afforded by the full stop. A nice contrast with the longer sentences nearby. _But this is off-topic on ELU as style guidance._

Comment: The only real issue is it should be *give up **and** be*, not *an be*.

Comment: A period works just fine. There are no subtleties in either the first sentence or the second so hardly any need for shading or restating. Just getting on with the idea, which you are doing.

Comment: So it should be "No matter how much pain my own path brings, I'll keep walking; I'll keep moving forward."?